# Singularity and residue in z = 0 - Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let's say we have the following two functions:

1. f(z) = cos(1/z) * (z+1)^2
2. g(z) = 1/(1+1/z)

For each function classify the singularity in z = 0 and determine the respective residues in z= 0.

Can you please show me how it is done for ONE of the two functions then if I understand that I can most likely do the other. I hope someone can help me out. Thanks !

Comment: Hint for the second one: $1/(1+1/z) = z/(1+z)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the well known Taylor expansions:

$$\cos\frac1z\cdot(z^2+2z+1)=\left(1-\frac1{2z^2}+\frac1{24z^4}-\ldots\right)(z^2+2z+1)=$$

$$=z^2+2z+\frac12-\frac1z-\frac{11}{24z^2}+\ldots$$